# Renaming date-stamped files to the previous day

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch-rename, mv

I want to rename the files in a directory to sequential numbers, based on this rule :
 **filename-[some date]** => **filename-[previous day's date]**

For example, `file20170329` `file20170328` and `file20170327` are to be renamed to `file20170328` `file20170327` and `file20170326`.

I have like 100 file, so I need a better trick than renaming each file individually.

Comment: should it support only *today's date => yesterday date* or *any-date to one day before*? should it support e.g. *20170301 -> 20170228*?

Comment: Yesterday date is a single "number" (20170329), how would you rename to yesterday two files? What is your actual goal?

Comment: Three questions: 1. while renaming, possible temporary dupes will occur, is that correct?  2. Do the files have extension? If so, always the same? 3. is "file" just an example, and is the date always on the same position in the name, and in the same format?

Comment: @Yaron: fortunately file dates are actually between 20170321 and 20170330. 
Uqbar : I want to rename all the files to yesterday, so at the end there will be only one file per day.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: 1- yes 2- all of them are .gz files 3- yes file is just an example , neither position nor  format are the same

Comment: Wait, the date format may vary? The script should recognize different date formats?

Comment: I tought you're talking about the "basename" format , it can be **file**20170327 or **randomstring**20170322 .. but date format is  the same

Comment: Ah, ok, missed the ping. Will post later today (almost need to teach) if no totally satisfying answer is posted before :)

Comment: @storm - can you please check if the code in my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @JacobVlijm : I managed to solve this with Yaron's trick , but your answers are always welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script:

- for each file
- If filename is greater than 8 (i.e. is able to hold a date)
- basefilename hold the filename without the last 8 chars
- TODAY - holds the last 8 chars (the date)
- YESTERDAY - holds one day before $TODAY as 8 chars
- Instead of using `mv` I created a `/tmp/storage` folder, and the script will copy the files to that location. This way, renaming one file won't corrupt another file if by any chance the basefilename for both files is the same, but the date is differ in one day

Note: In order to allow the script to execute the `cp` one should remove the `echo` from the `echo cp ...` line

```
mkdir -p /tmp/storage
for f in *
do
  if [ "${#f}" -gt 8 ]; then
    filebasename=${f::-8}
    TODAY=${f: -8}
    YESTERDAY=`date '+%C%y%m%d' -d "$TODAY-1 days"`
    echo cp $f /tmp/storage/${f//$TODAY}$YESTERDAY; 
  fi
done
```

example:

```
$ ls *20*
aaa2hhh20170329  aaahhh20170329  xajds20170222  xajsxs20170224
```

script result:

```
cp aaa2hhh20170329 /tmp/storage/aaa2hhh20170328
cp aaahhh20170329 /tmp/storage/aaahhh20170328
cp xajds20170222 /tmp/storage/xajds20170221
cp xajsxs20170224 /tmp/storage/xajsxs20170223
```

Comment: I think you can just use a shell glob, `for f in *`, instead of running ls. Bash sorts the filenames given by glob anyway.

Comment: @Zanna - can you please double check? for each file, the original date is taken and is replaced with the previous day

Comment: It's working with some adjustments , thanks :)

Comment: @storm - great, I've made a few adjustments myself a few seconds ago (using cp to /tmp/storage instead of mv)

Comment: Maybe I was testing an earlier version. Can't check now but looks like it should work and OP says it does, so +1!

Comment: @Zanna thanks! (+1 to your working solution as well)

Answer (score 4):

If you have 100 files (and have access to perl `rename`, generally the case in Ubuntu) you could use:

```
for n in {100..1}; do rename -n "s/$(date --date="$n days ago" +"%Y%m%d")/$(date --date="$(($n+1)) days ago" +"%Y%m%d")/" *; done
```

Now, when you use `-n` for testing, it complains like this:

```
rename(file20170217, file20170216)
file20170218 not renamed: file20170217 already exists
file20170219 not renamed: file20170218 already exists
```

But when you run it without `-n` the file no longer exists, so the renaming is successful:

```
for n in {100..1}; do rename "s/$(date --date="$n days ago" +"%Y%m%d")/$(date --date="$(($n+1)) days ago" +"%Y%m%d")/" *; done
```

If you have more than 100 files, you need to increase the range to `{150..1}` or whatever.

This is very slow. It will take maybe 2 minutes or more to rename 100 files. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

or if you prefer GUI approach, give krename a try, it has a lot of modules and you can write custom scripts in it, "date system function", "date time plugin" could work for you[image: Krename GUI for plugins]

http://www.krename.net/home/

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```